# Overtwisted contact forms on open manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, contact-geometry

I tried first at [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982801/overtwisted-contact-forms-without-closed-reeb-orbits) but got no answers, so I thought maybe this question belongs here.

It is known that on *closed* $3$-manifolds the Reeb vector field of any contact form inducing an overtwisted contact structure has closed orbits, a theorem due to Hofer. I wonder what is currently know about Reeb orbits of overtwisted contact structures on manifolds that are not closed. Is there any known example of an open overtwisted $3$-manifold whithout any closed Reeb orbits?

Since the Reeb vector field for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its canonical contact structure is just $\partial_z$ and has no closed orbits I thought the likely example of an open manifold with an overtwisted contact structure without closed Reeb orbits would be $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its canonical overtwisted contact form.
Using cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$, this contact form is given by  $$\lambda_{OT} = \cos(r)dz + r\sin(r)d\theta.$$ Since I couldn't find any explicit calculation of the Reeb vector field associated to this form in any book or paper, I tried to determine it on my on and arrived at
$$
R(r, \theta, z)= \begin{cases} 2\left(0, \frac{\sin(r)}{\sin(2r) + 2r}, \frac{\sin(r)+ r\cos(r)}{\sin(2r) + 2r}\right), \text{  if  } r \neq 0, \\ \left(0, \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right) \text{  if  } r = 0, \end{cases} 
$$
which is continuous at $r = 0$ and satisfies the equalities $\lambda_{OT}(R) = 1$ and $d\lambda_{OT}(R, \cdot) = 0$. I don't know if this is completely correct because I had a feeling the Reeb vector field at the line $r=0$ should be $\partial_z$, since the contact form reduces to $dz$ in this case. Anyway, I was unable to give explicit integral curves for the vector field $R$ or to conclude if there are any closed orbits, so I'm still not sure whether $(\mathbb{R}^3, \lambda_{OT})$ is an example of overtwisted $3$-manifold without closed Reeb orbits or not. Moreover, any example of overtwisted contact structure without closed orbits will satisfy my curiosity, really.

Comment: I'm not really too familiar with the topic, but can't you just like, remove a few points from a manifold? I think it doesn't break the property of being overtwisted. So if we had a manifold with discrete set of closed orbits of the Reeb field it would give you the desired example.

Just need to pick these points away from the overtwisted disk, is this possible?

Comment: Hi Douglas, and welcome. Please add a link to the MSE thread next time you cross-post. (I've done it here.) Also, I think it's good form to wait a bit longer (say, one week) before cross-posting.

Comment: More about the maths: if your computations are correct (which I think they are, perhaps up to a factor of 2), then all cylinders $r =$ const are invariant and if $r = -\tan r$, they are foliated by closed orbits.

Comment: That's correct. The first value of $r$ satisfying $r = -\tan r$ occurs before $2\pi$, which is the radius of the overtwisted disc in this structure. So I can't just restrict $\lambda_{OT}$ to a ball around the origin, for any ball large enough to contain the overtwisted disc will also contain a portion of the foliated cylinder. I also can't remove lines from this cylinder, as Lev sugested, because this would remove points from the overtwisted disc. I guess $(\mathbb{R}^3, \lambda_{OT})$ can't provide an example then.

Comment: I would guess that there exists no aperiodic overtwisted contact form. This can maybe be deduced from the Weinstein conjecture for manifolds with boundary (Corollary 4.7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.09148). Please note that this is currently unproven, in the above-mentioned paper it is a corollary of Conjecture 4.3. However, it is proven in some special cases, see for example (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1269658&loc=fromreflist or https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08603).